# what is the best way to making this layout height growing

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please check this website layout image:

[image: layout]

I want to make the height grows as the content height. The only way I have in mind is by changing the height of a div by jquery to complete the design. And I'm searching for the best solution for this kind of layouts

Comment: Where would the content be located exactly?

Comment: @Robin it'll be inside the floded background

Comment: @aug still under construction, just want other opinion of what the best way to code it

Answer (score 0):

[image: home]

Not sure what are the black "box" and the blue ribbon, so I considered them as some sort of header. But anyways, I hope you'll get the idea and you'll be able to modify my code to your needs.

```
<div id="header" class="green">
    <!-- Green section, header of the page -->
</div>
<div id="content" class="red">
    <!-- This #content div should have the red zone as a background -->
    <div class="content-header yellow">
        <!-- Yellow section, header of the content -->
    </div>
    <div class="content-body">
        <p>Your content</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="purple">

</div>
```

The `#content` div should have the red part as a background, a thin pattern that can be repeated vertically.

The `.content-header` div is what I considered to be the header, it should have the yellow part as a background.

But basically, the idea is to have a header (green), a content area with a background that can be repeated vertically (red), and a footer (purple).